# How to download pdf using nodejs/express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to download pdf from a URL using the below code. example URL is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cricket/cricket_tutorial.pdf

```js
axios({method:'get',encoding:null, url: scraping_url, responseType: 'stream',headers: { "Content-type": "application/pdf"}}).then((response) => {
            res.set("Content-type", "application/pdf")
            response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('12345678.pdf'))
            
          })
```

But I am getting

[image]

So, how should I download ans display it on chrome?

Comment: the file is on your server or you want to download from other's website into your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cricket/cricket_tutorial.pdf#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

If you want to use backend server, use:

```js
router.get('/pdfroute', (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method:'get',
        url: scraping_url,
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    .then(response => {
        res.set('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
        res.set('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="'+filename+'"'
        response.data.pipe(res)
    })
})
```

Comment: I want to directly download it from my express server and show it on chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I [managed](https://api.scrapingdog.com/scrape?api_key=apiKey&url=https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cricket/cricket_tutorial.pdf) to do it